# How to generate a map with clusters in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe below and I would like to know how I can make a graph similar to the one I inserted in the attachment. Can you help with some material or some code that helps? See that I have the properties and also the corresponding cluster of each property, but I don't know how to generate a map like the one I inserted.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Properties':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
'Latitude':[-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267],
'Longitude':[-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702],
'cluster': (1,2,1,2,1,2)})

display(df)

Properties Latitude Longitude cluster
0   1     -24.930473 -49.994889   1
1   2     -24.955750 -49.990162   2
2   3     -24.924161 -50.004343   1
3   4     -24.955790 -50.007371   2
4   5     -24.945570 -50.015420   1
5   6     -24.932670 -50.007020   2
```

**Example**

[image]

Comment: (1) To display a map like that you need some knowledge of the boundaries. If you just need some kind of blob shapes around your points then please add that to the question. Otherwise, please add something about the boundaries (like which country/island you're looking at). (2) This looks a lot like they used some kind of piecewise-linear discriminator (decision tree, random forest, ...) to generate the boundary between the two clusters. Once your question is updated with boundary information I or somebody else can throw together some code to do that.

Comment: Hi @Hans, Thanks for replying. My main aim is to generate the points on the map and a color around the points to show that they make up different clusters. The boundary issue between the two is not my concern at the moment, it's that on this map it was. These are properties belonging to the State of Paraná, which is in Brazil.